# C func signature inside Linux Kernel: include/linux/sched.h

Tags: c++, c, function

Again found once of those arcane function definitions inside linux kernel. The signature of the function reads:

```
static void __sched __schedule(void)
```

Now it has both `void` and `__sched` as the return type. Can someone please explain what those identifiers are doing there. Shouldn’t it be either void`or`__sched`? How can it be both?

This is the definition of `__sched`:

```
 #define __sched    __attribute__((__section__(".sched.text")))
```

Comment: Both `__attribute__` and `__section__` are covered by the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). Its a "put me here" kinda thing. Further, the top-hit searching google for ["gcc \_\_atttribute\_\_ \_\_section\_\_"](http://forum.kernelnewbies.org/read.php?14,822) will tell you pretty much *exactly* what you're asking.

Comment: Be sure to use `extern "C" {}` for the declaration if you use [tag:c++]!

Comment: Are you writing C++ code that runs in the kernel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void` is a standard C type, indicating that the function doesn't return a result.

`__sched` is a macro that expands in accordance with the definition you quoted, making the declaration equivalent to:

```
static void __attribute__((__section__(".sched.text"))) __schedule(void)
```

`__attribute__` is a language extension supported by gcc (and by compilers compatible with gcc). Its meaning is documented in the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). It specifies that the generated code for the function should be placed in a specified section in the object file.

Since `__sched`, or rather the sequence that it expands to, is not a type name, there's no conflict between it and `void`.

(The double parentheses in the syntax of `__attribute__` allow a macro definition like

```
#define __attribute__(arg)
```

to be used if you want to compile the code with a compiler that doesn't support that extension, causing it to be ignored rather than treated as a syntax error. Some attributes take multiple arguments; wrapping the entire argument list in an extra set of parentheses allows the entire list to be treated, as far as the preprocessor is concerned, as a single argument.)

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, thanks. But the last few lines what do you mean when you say "to be used if you want to compile the code with a compiler that doesn't support that extension, causing it to be ignored rather than treated as a syntax error. " - What extensions are you referring to? ---Thanks

Comment: `__attribute__` is a language extension, supported by gcc but not by all other compilers. For a compiler that doesn't support it, `__attribute__((...))` is a syntax error. I was pointing out that the double parentheses syntax enables a workaround for compiling gcc-specific code with non-gcc compilers. It's not particularly relevant to your question (the Linux kernel can't be compiled with a non-gcc-compatible compiler).